# Get name of tax rule applied in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

How can i get the tax rule name applied on my product.

I have tried `getfulltaxinfo()` but it is getting me rate & all stuffs but not the name of tax rule that is applied. Is there any way i can get the tax rule name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get tax class name with following code:

```
$taxClassId = $_product->getTaxClassId();
$taxClassName = Mage::getModel('tax/class')->load($taxClassId)->getClassName();
```